# I have an insert into statement but there's an error with a comma and i just cant fix it

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Here's the code i have to do but it gives an error saying the code has not been ended correctly and I
cant see the problem, maybe I am just blind but i dont know.

```
 INSERT INTO Customer VALUES
    (11011, 'Jeffery', 'Smith', '18 Water RD', 0877277521, 'jef@isat.com'),(its giving me an error here and saying the statement hasn't ended correctly)
    (11012, 'Alex', 'Hendricks', '22 Water Rd', 0863257857 , 'ah@mcom.com'),
    (11013 , 'Johnson', 'Clark', '101 Summer Lane', 0834567891,'jclark@mcom.co.za'),
    (11014 , 'Henry', 'Jones', '55 Mountain Way',0612547895 ,'hj@isat.co.za'),
    (11015 , 'Andre', 'Williams', '5 Main Rd ', 0827238521,'aw@mcal.co.za');
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle only supports inserting on row at a time.  The simplest solution is multiple inserts:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (11011, 'Jeffery', 'Smith', '18 Water RD', 0877277521, 'jef@isat.com');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (11012, 'Alex', 'Hendricks', '22 Water Rd', 0863257857 , 'ah@mcom.com');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (11013 , 'Johnson', 'Clark', '101 Summer Lane', 0834567891,'jclark@mcom.co.za');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (11014 , 'Henry', 'Jones', '55 Mountain Way',0612547895 ,'hj@isat.co.za');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (11015 , 'Andre', 'Williams', '5 Main Rd ', 0827238521,'aw@mcal.co.za');
```

Other solutions are to use `insert all` or to convert the statements from `values` to `select . . . from dual union all`.

I would also advise you to explicitly list the the columns, to help prevent inadvertent errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INSERT ALL` statement

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO Customer VALUES (11011, 'Jeffery', 'Smith', '18 Water RD', 0877277521, 'jef@isat.com')
  INTO Customer VALUES (11012, 'Alex', 'Hendricks', '22 Water Rd', 0863257857 , 'ah@mcom.com')
  INTO Customer VALUES (11013 , 'Johnson', 'Clark', '101 Summer Lane', 0834567891,'jclark@mcom.co.za')
  INTO Customer VALUES (11014 , 'Henry', 'Jones', '55 Mountain Way',0612547895 ,'hj@isat.co.za')
  INTO Customer VALUES (11015 , 'Andre', 'Williams', '5 Main Rd ', 0827238521,'aw@mcal.co.za')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8e14a7e0fcb21833b19f0b0a9bd5034)